# how to save darkmode in local Storage by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, darkmode

I need help ....

how to save dark mode in local storage?

My js Code :

```
$(function() {
    $("body").append("<button class='Nightbtn' onclick='DarkMode()'><img src='/Assets/Imgs/Png/night.png' alt=''></button>")
});
      
      function DarkMode() {
        let element = document.body;
        element.classList.toggle("Night");
      }
```

help pls

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do really has two parts - the saving of the `darkmode` state and the loading of that same state when the page is reloaded.

I tried creating this as a `snippet` but weirdly kept getting a `script error` wih no details yet it works fine locally. The two methods of interest are `getItem` and `setItem`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .Night{
                background:black;
                color:white;
            }
        </style>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
        
            const _store='darkmode';
            const _class='Night';
            
            function DarkMode() {
              document.body.classList.toggle( _class );
              localStorage.setItem( _store, document.body.classList.contains( _class ) ? 1 : 0 )
            }
            
            $(document).ready(()=>{
                $('body').append("<button class='Nightbtn' onclick='DarkMode()'><img src='/Assets/Imgs/Png/night.png' alt=''></button>");
                
                let dm=localStorage.getItem( _store );
                if( Number(dm)==1 )document.body.classList.add( _class );       
                
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Store your mode as storage!

```
localStorage.setItem("Night", true);
```

> To get

```
localStorage.getItem('Night')
```